# Not able to handle special characters for mobile app element locator using robot framework and appium

Tags: eclipse, appium, robotframework

I am trying to test a mobile app using robot framework, appium and eclipse as IDE. My app login has to be clicked using the elements class and content-desc but when I copy the content-desc I notice a special character (Log In) which doesn't get saved in eclipse.

Please help me to find the x path using login or even without it.
PFA the screenshot of the elements at https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE3pg.png

Comment: Are you asking how to fix eclipse, or how to use robot? What if you use some other editor to properly type in the character -- will the robot test run?

Comment: No, I am just asking if there is any way to handle these kind of characters.I tried in another editor where this value got saved still it didn't worked.

Comment: It seems i can use starts-with to match the name of that element and in that way special character can be ignored e.g xpath=//*[starts-with(@content-desc,'Log')] ,thanks bryan problem is solved now

Answer (score 0):

In my case, special character was coming due to the icon associated with the text.

For Appium, it's better to use accessibility ids for finding the elements.

Hope this helps :)